# How can I get the Double.toString() behaviour AND thousands separator?

Tags: java, format, double, separator

I want to add the thousands separator to a variable of type `double`. I have tried using `String.format("%,f", x);` and similar, but it seems to have a fixed number of decimal places, unlike `Double.toString()`.

**For example**, with the value 1234.5:

`Double.toString()`: 1234.5
`String.format()`: 1.234,500000
Desired: 1.234,5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`NumberFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class knows the decimal separator to use for your user's locale.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
String formattedDouble = formatter.format(1234.5);
```

You may use the `setMaximumFractionDigits` method if this gives you too many decimal places.

Comment: Thanks, `NumberFormat` didn't work perfectly, but a subclass of it, `DecimalFormat`, did.

Comment: For other thousand and decimal separators, you can specify the locale in `NumberFormat.getInstance()`